# How to automaticaly convert text to url

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list with names and I want to make an other colum with http://name.jpg

is this possible in excel?

and if my original name was 2 words or more can I have auto underscores in the url instead of spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `=CONCATENATE("http://"; A1; ".jpg")`

Comment: @xangr This looks like a viable solution to the asker's question.  Please post your response as an answer, not as a comment.  That way it can be accepted as a solution and you can earn reputation for it.

Comment: None of the answers except one actually produces a hyperlink.

Comment: @jbarker2160 The question doesn't specify that a hyperlink is needed.

Comment: @Excellll, So...the question does not contain blue, underlined text that may be clicked?

Comment: If you need commas to be treated specially also, [edit] your question to say so.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=CONCATENATE("http://"; A1; ".jpg")`

Also, this will detect spaces and **split** them with **slash**:

`=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1; " "; ""))=LEN(A1); CONCATENATE("http://"; A1; ".jpg"); CONCATENATE("http://"; LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1)-1); "/"; MID(A1;FIND(" ";A1; 999); ".jpg"))`

This will detect spaces and **replace** them with **underscore**:

`=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1; " "; ""))=LEN(A1); CONCATENATE("http://"; A1; ".jpg"); CONCATENATE("http://"; SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_"); ".jpg"))`

Comment: Hi, that is a very good idea but I 'll give you an example of some names I have for example I have "Anafenza, the Foremost" in one cell and I need to remove the spaces, comas, and replace spaces with _ for the final format

Comment: @AlexStavrianos, sure. Update the original post.

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_"),",",""), ".jpg"))
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
="http://"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_")&".jpg"
```

This should meet both requirements.